# sharepoint designer 2007

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web, web-parts, sharepoint-designer

I'm not an expert using Sharepoint Designer 2007, then i need some help to maintaince a website.

I have a page and need to add a .aspx that already exists inside the website. When i click on add WebPart, there is some WebParts to be choosen, but the aspx that i need looks to be inside a Webpart. Some like this:

I got a menu 'Recruiting', and it contains some aspx like 'New Jobs.aspx', another one 'New employees.aspx'. I need to add the page 'New Jobs.aspx' inside the page 'New employees.aspx' as example. But when i click on add webpart, this aspx doesn't appear to be choosen.

How can i do this?

Thanks and so sorry for bad english and terrible knowledge about Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add one page as a web part to another page, it just does not make any sense. What you can do is find out what web part (it can be a list view web part) is located on the page you are trying to add. Then you can just add the same web part to the first page.